# A specific transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon. I have doubts with this problem. Find the expression for the linear transformation $T$ knowing that the line joining the point $v = (x, y)$ with $T (v)$ is horizontal and also its midpoint is on the line $y = x$.

My idea: I made a graphic representation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ taking a point $v$ coordinate $(x, y)$ and draw a horizontal line on it and then realized that $T$ does not affect the $y$-coordinate, but when I draw the line $y = x$ not know what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{T(x,y)+(x,y)}{2} = (r,r)$$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$. We can write $T(x,y) = (T_1(x,y), T_2(x,y))$, then $$\frac{T_1(x,y)+x}{2} = r =\frac{T_2(x,y)+y}{2}, $$
which implies $T_1(x,y)+x=T_2(x,y)+y$.

Also, we know the line is horizontal, so $T_2(x,y)=y$. Therefore $T_1(x,y)+x=2y\implies T_1(x,y) = 2y-x$. From this we get $$T(x,y) = (2y-x, y) = x(-1,0) + y(2,1).$$

Note that $$T(\alpha v)=T(\alpha (v_1,v_2))=(2\alpha v_2-\alpha v_1, \alpha v_2) = \alpha(2v_2-v_1,v_2)=\alpha T(v) $$
and
$$T(u+v) = T(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2) = (2u_2+2v_2-u_1-v_1,u_2+v_2)=$$
$$= (2u_2-u_1,u_2)+(2v_2-v_1,v_2) = T(u)+T(v),$$
so $T$ is in fact linear.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are very kind.